# Consistancy of pairs in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists of the same length, and I wish to find out what percentage of all possible pairs of list indices' values have the same relationship for the two lists, in my case greater than (or sign(list[index_1] - list[index_2])).

Here is my slow implementation:

```
from itertools import combinations
import random
import numpy as np

values_lists = []
for i in range(4):
    value_list = []
    for j in range(50):
        value_list.append(random.random())
    values_lists.append(value_list)
#

total = 0.
n = 0

for list_1, list_2 in combinations(values_lists, 2):
    for index_1, index_2 in combinations(range(len(list_1)), 2):
        if np.sign(list_1[index_2] - list_1[index_1]) == np.sign(list_2[index_2] - list_2[index_1]):
            total += 1
        
        n += 1

print(total / n)
```

I'm wondering if anyone has a faster solution, as this takes some time.

Comment: By stylish, do you mean faster? Or more compact in term of lines of code ?

Comment: This script as-written doesnt run... Python doesn't know where you got this `combinations()` function.

Comment: values_lists has length 4-8 and values_lists[0] has length 50.

Comment: @Omroth, I'd strongly recommend that you use an IDE that automatically lints, and checks syntax.  In the long run this will be very useful.  As an example, I use `vim` and configured it to run [`ale`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/), `flake8`, `pycodestyle` and `vulture` while I code... I catch many errors like this

Comment: I have updated the post with a snippet which I have verified runs (previously it was lifted and manually edited from a longer piece of code)

Comment: I'm running it a lot.  Also, are you serious that you think 0.2 seconds isn't slow?  What if I had to do it per-frame?

Comment: Do you have a speed goal in mind? I just added a solution that's ~48 times faster, taking me about 0.00025 seconds. How fast is fast enough? For something even faster I might need to think of a different algorithm (or learn how to use Numba).

Comment: triu_indices is the key, thank you Kelly (and others), much appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precomputing the signs for each list (and not using NumPy) makes it about 14 times faster (`solution2`), and doing the same with mostly NumPy makes it about 48 times faster (`solution3`).

```
11.52 ms  solution1
 0.82 ms  solution2
 0.25 ms  solution3

11.35 ms  solution1
 0.81 ms  solution2
 0.24 ms  solution3

11.42 ms  solution1
 0.83 ms  solution2
 0.26 ms  solution3
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTLkpswELzzFXPZWinxEsDZy1b8JRRFCSNvlAKJSCIV7887GgksMHYSLujR0zPqHmk42@9K7i@Xlp/AqG60Qsmc/GLdyE3dCWMNfUvAfVZZ1sEBstRPJQ4TPzwpDYis8134FyAkHFXfCMmQz6z4dlBMlHOwkC3/jdFhsA3XTL5z0nFJQh5K1yT4iRPIITXifQaVE1sFL7BaySsKh8MaXWzQRUSvE0UxPh8gX23JuKS5HbWcgF9AJslS4eKewljNtOLELa/M5UuOp2PwDRrgneHg542bszDPYhWoJ9u5zVsNO2NRtGqlvFtE4LIYv189tnwODdU608Jga9riOGu3vEpo5kRBVyXh4kwbWD/EQG6zbc0PcWhsiPynaX93aH/3Dmgx1q4txJGjRa6Dliu@QZdRZVa5Rp3OFwpnWrPz2t5Bq7b2u@WS7f@MulqOu6UryCdAs2@cjllmpG9@/I@N1exoUzVarolrHkan4Js2eNQFsy2PeiAc@k4ThGhXyQdPNi6F4KujpqCu1J7QB@adRnlEYa@P2C7etjjcO6BWPVjRc@Ek7QelrWMbOLNhRzgRrFKdmTeXBwoQNXDNLD5cAcF/JjMRk63q55kc@@EMzLhGSZKldeh/lfinDyULz9vXSR0P9LgAm6X@EaGv2ULJiE/ZMHDZklBFGn6E0kg75Z@BMZQmvhwUEdN4MUOKQQtpCS6sb8QUUceq9nQZQa@F3yH1Rrvj9UKSID7pWN@07A22mXYoZMP1Ic8odWbn2eLuYKrnp9e0OEFv4BmegFj4BDnfuzjkSutasp7XNb1c/gA)):

```
def solution1(values_lists):
    total = 0.
    n = 0

    for list_1, list_2 in combinations(values_lists, 2):
        for index_1, index_2 in combinations(range(len(list_1)), 2):
            if np.sign(list_1[index_2] - list_1[index_1]) == np.sign(list_2[index_2] - list_2[index_1]):
                total += 1
            n += 1
    return total / n

def solution2(values_lists):
    signs_lists = [
        [-1 if a < b else 1 if b < a else 0
         for a, b in combinations(lst, 2)]
        for lst in values_lists
    ]
    total = 0.
    n = 0
    for signs_1, signs_2 in combinations(signs_lists, 2):
        n += len(signs_1)
        for sign_1, sign_2 in zip(signs_1, signs_2):
            if sign_1 == sign_2:
                total += 1
    return total / n

def solution3(values_lists):
    triu_indices = np.triu_indices(len(values_lists[0]), 1)
    signs_arrays = [
        prod_signs[triu_indices]
        for lst in values_lists
        for a in [np.array(lst)]
        for prod_signs in [np.sign(np.subtract.outer(a, a))]
    ]
    total = 0
    n = 0
    for signs1, signs2 in combinations(signs_arrays, 2):
        n += signs1.size
        total += (signs1 == signs2).sum()
    return total / n

funcs = solution1, solution2, solution3

from timeit import repeat
from itertools import combinations
from operator import eq
import random
import numpy as np

values_lists = []
for i in range(4):
    value_list = []
    for j in range(50):
        value_list.append(random.random())
    values_lists.append(value_list)

for func in funcs:
    print(func(values_lists))

for _ in range(3):
    print()
    for func in funcs:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(values_lists), number=10)) / 10
        print('%5.2f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Kelly Bundy 's answer, you can make `solution2` even faster by summing a generator expression rather than the nested for loop:

```
def generatorway():
    signs_lists = (
        [-1 if a < b else 1 if b < a else 0
         for a, b in combinations(lst, 2)]
        for lst in values_lists)
    combos = list(combinations(signs_lists, 2))
    n = sum(len(i) for i, _ in combos)
    total = sum(1 for i, j in combos for k, m in zip(i, j) if k==m)
    return total/n
```

Speed comparison with `values_lists = [[random.random() for _ in range(500)] for _ in range(4)]`:

```
print(generatorway())
print(solution2())
%timeit generatorway()
%timeit solution2()
```

Output:

```
0.4931048764195057
0.4931048764195057
66.9 ms ± 58.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
68.6 ms ± 38.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I had tried a similar one and it was slower. Tried yours now, seems to be the same speed, both take about 0.82 ms.

Comment: I think that's because (going off your code below) you only do 3 repeats as opposed to the 70 I've done, I consistently find that the generator expression is ~2.5% faster

Comment: Actually I do 150 times (3\*5\*10). I suspect it's because we use different Python versions (what are you using?) or because of your longer lists.

Comment: I find using generators is faster regardless of the length of the lists originally I was using 3.8.13, but I've checked in 3.9.12 and 3.10.4 and I'm still finding the generators are faster

Comment: I've only tried it on tio.run with it's pre-3.8. Might try with a newer version elsewhere later, but I just added a NumPy-heavy solution that's more than three times faster anyway :-). For your longer lists, it's even over four times faster. I'm btw still wondering whether there's also an algorithm with a better complexity class than the brute-force we've been doing so far...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best help I can offer is with formatting and organization.  You should break your functions into pieces that operate independently.

I also simplified your nested list builder to use a list comprehension.

This doesn't address your code speed concerns, but I couldn't find anything slow when I run the script in question...

```py
from itertools import combinations
import random
import numpy as np
from loguru import logger

@logger.catch
def build_nested_lists(inner_list_size=50, outer_list_size=4):
    values_lists = []
    for ii in range(outer_list_size):
        value_list = [random.random() for jj in range(inner_list_size)]
        values_lists.append(value_list)
    return values_lists


@logger.catch
def handle_nested_lists(
    values_lists=None,
):
    assert isinstance(values_lists, (list, tuple))
    total = 0.0
    n = 0

    for list_1, list_2 in combinations(values_lists, 2):
        for index_1, index_2 in combinations(range(len(list_1)), 2):
            if np.sign(list_1[index_2] - list_1[index_1]) == np.sign(
                list_2[index_2] - list_2[index_1]
            ):
                total += 1
            n += 1
    return total / n

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(handle_nested_lists(build_nested_lists(50, 4)))
```